# Is it possible to resize a block component for CircuitTikz in Latex?

Tags: overleaf, circuitikz, resize

I'm struggling to change the width/height of a directional coupler component provided by CircuiTikz package. Its code is given by:

```
 node [coupler2, rotate =90, scale = 1](d.c){};
```

which produces the following image.

[image]

I can easily re-scale the component using the scale function, however, I want to change the width of that component so that it looks more appealing. I tried to insert a width variable as such: `node [coupler2, rotate =90, scale = 1, width = 0.1cm](d.c){}`; but it doesn't appear to do anything. I've scrolled through the documentation on CircuiTikz and it was also a dead end.

Comment: Just to clarify that the component itself falls into the "blocks" class in circuiTikzs

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your question.

Really blocks are not though to be "adjusted" differently in width and height, but you can scale them asymmetrically as every Ti*k*Z node:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \draw (0,0) node[coupler2]{}
          (3,0) node[coupler2, scale=1.2]{}
          (6,0) node[coupler2, xscale=1.5]{}
          ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: asymmetric scaling of nodes]

Another possibility is to use the (internal, undocumented, unsupported, may change in the future) `width` key, which acts differently:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \draw (0,0) node[coupler2,xscale=2]{};
    \draw (4,0) node[coupler2,circuitikz/quadpoles/coupler2/width=2.6]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: difference between xscale and width]

Comment: Yes, asymmetric rescaling is exactly what I was looking for! I just didn't know where to look to find arguments such as "xscale", and "yscale" for the node. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: These are Ti*k*Z coordinate transformations: https://tikz.dev/tikz-transformations#pgf./tikz/xscale